# How to display jQuery UI dialog in submit button's onclick and prevent form submission?

Tags: forms, javascript

I'm using Drupal 7 and [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module set to jQuery version 1.8. I have a form. In it's definition I have:

```
$form['#attached']['library'] = array(
  array('system', 'ui.dialog'),
  array('aat_pc_product', 'product_form'),
);
```

In the behavior, I use:

```
if(!isFormValid) {
  $('<div>' + Drupal.t('Some fields was left blank even when not disabled. Either check "skip line" or fill missing data.') + '</div>').dialog({ modal: true });
}

return isFormValid;
```

Now, with good old `alert` it worked great. But when I try do use `dialog`, in chrome in my console I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'curCSS' jquery.ui.position.min.js?v=1.8.7:13

In FireFox it fails in similar way:

> TypeError: c.curCSS is not a function
>   ...his,"marginTop",true))||0,v=l+p+parseInt(c.curCSS(this,"marginRight",true))||0,w...
>   jquery...v=1.8.7 (row 13)

Updating to dev version of [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) and seelcting jQuery 1.9 or 1.10 does not help - it does not complain about `curCSS`, but about lack of `$.browser()` that was removed in jQuery 1.9, and deprecated long ago.

My question is: Am I doing something wrong, or it's a bug between jQuery Update and Drupal? And if it's a bug, is there any version of jQuery update without it?

Is there a way to update jQuery UI to make it match jQuery, without hacking jQuery Update module or updating directly in D:\UniServer\www\misc\ui ?

Comment: It'll probably be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048271/jquery-ui-1-8-13-sudden-error

Comment: @Clive Good catch, it didn't occur to me it might be something so fundamental.

Comment: Have you checked this link: https://drupal.org/node/1847900

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal It was closed as a duplicate of an issue that's closed (fixed) too. But it does not work for me. That's why I was thinking I may be doing something wrong. Opened an issue in issue queue, but in the meantime I'm still looking for a way to hack it together.

Answer (score -1):

when c.curCSS is not a function error occures ,just do the following
if any two js included check and remove .. after add this into script

```
jQuery.curCSS = jQuery.css;
```